# YUI 3.5 App Framework server routing

Tags: model-view-controller, yui3, progressive-enhancement

I am currently looking at implementing YUI 3.5 pr1 (and then the final version when released) in a fairly large application.

The backend is built with PHP and MySQL using a MVC structure with a front controller pattern. By it self, the server can process URLs (http://mysite.com/module/submodule/option) etc and return a fully rendered page.

I would like to implement the App Framework in YUI across the whole application so that javascript-enabled browser will effectively have something like a 1-page app with history management avaliable.

I am currently looking at the app framework docs on the [staging site](http://stage.yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/). Unfortunately, the docs aren't complete (in particular sections on routing coordination with server and progressively enhanced apps).

In any case, if a user visits http://mysite.com/modules/submodule/option with an HTML4 browser (all versions of IE), and he has javascript enabled, he would need to be redirected to http://mysite.com/#/modules/submodule/option.

Is this something that's built into the App Framework? I would prefer to utilise a solution that does not require the whole page to be rendered out and then redirected to the hashtaged URL and then rerendered again.

Finally, I have watched the [intro video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCexiX_eUJA&ei=Rk4mT83qJMiViQeRz42aBA&usg=AFQjCNHbWQMuA6eYm3tSAF6RB6X-Dhm3zA) on the App Framework and it mentioned that they are using the Handlebars template engine. I am using [Twig](http://twig-project.net) as my template engine on the server side. Is it possible to use an alternative template engine with the app framework? In particular the [twig js engine](https://github.com/schmittjoh/twig.js).